# Blocked page stripe checkout

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, backend, blocked

I keep geting

The page at (domain) was not allowed to display insecure content from (local host)

Any ideas what’s causing this

I have tried everything

server

```
app.post("/checkout", async (req, res) => {
  const items = req.body.items;
  let lineItems = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    lineItems.push({
      price: item.id,
      quantity: item.quantity,
    });
  });

  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    line_items: lineItems,
    mode: "payment",
    success_url: "http://localhost:3000/success",
    cancel_url: "http://localhost:3000/store",
    shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ["GB"] },
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: "fixed_amount",
          fixed_amount: { amount: 195, currency: "GBP" },
          display_name: "Standard shipping",
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: { unit: "business_day", value: 3 },
            maximum: { unit: "business_day", value: 5 },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        shipping_rate_data: {
          type: "fixed_amount",
          fixed_amount: { amount: 495, currency: "GBP" },
          display_name: "Next Day Shipping",
          delivery_estimate: {
            minimum: { unit: "business_day", value: 1 },
            maximum: { unit: "business_day", value: 2 },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  res.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      url: session.url,
    })
  );
});

app.listen(4000, () => console.log("Listening on port 4000!"));
```

as you can see from about i have attached my server and frontend i also have checked over the stripe docs and it looks like i have done everything requested

client

```
const checkout = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("https://localhost:4000/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ items: cart.items }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.url) {
          window.location.assign(response.url); // Forwarding user to Stripe
        }
      });
  };
```

Comment: Can you share more details ? how are you creating and loading the Checkout Session ?

Comment: i have just added my code any help would be appreciated